# Can I have appsettings.config MVC 6-style in a WCF project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multi project solution, with one entry point being a WCF service, and one being an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. The webapp uses a json file for settings, wcf uses web.config. Any ideas on how to make these both usable from a common class library project(e.g. repository.dll).

Comment: yes, it's possible, you can build your own ConfigurationProvider and make it read from the web.config

Comment: Yes but configuration transformation will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet would be to have a common JSON file for both application for configuration.

Yes, I know... it skips the goodies of all this Web.Config and everything. But here's what I think... deserializing a JSON file will literally take no time in any languages. The only thing you need to make sure, is that no one is downloading that file if it contains sensitive information. `web.config` file are protected in IIS and can't be downloaded.

ASP.NET 5 projects are `wwwroot`ed at a different level.

So the easiest solution? Configuration in a JSON file that deserialize into a static type.

Comment: I kinda went this way afterall, having a global configuration in a common project.